# Use Google AutoML to classify articles in Indonesian language

Tags: google-cloud-nl, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

Is it possible to create custom text/content classification model using Indonesian language dataset and then use it to classify articles written in Indonesian language? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to try this out. We're not advertising Indonesian as a supported language, but you should be able to try and see how well the model works.